# Google Analytics transaction currency using query parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm porting some code that uses analytics.js to a platform where I need to manually construct the gif query string (due to security limitations of the platform with js files from external sources).

I build the tracking url like so:

```
    trackingUrl = URL   +'?utmwv=1'             // Tracking code version
    +'&utmn='+utmn          // Unique ID generated for each GIF request to prevent caching of the GIF image.
    +'&utmt=transaction'    // Indicates the type of request, which is one of: event, transaction, item, or custom variable. If this value is not present in the GIF request, the request is typed as page.
    +'&utmtid='+trackingNumber
    +'&utmsr=-'             // Screen resolution    
    +'&utmsc=-'             // Screen color depth
    +'&utmul=-'             // Browser language
    +'&utmje=0'             // Indicates if browser is Java-enabled. 1 is true. 
    +'&utmfl=-'             // Flash Version
    +'&utmdt='+(typeof description == 'string'?description:'-') // Page title, which is a URL-encoded string.
    +'&utmp='+site          // Page request of the current page.                             
    +'&utmac='+ACCOUNT_CODE // Account String. Appears on all requests.
    +'&utmtst='+encodeUriComponent(affiliate)
    +'&utmtto='+orderTotal
    +'&utmtsp='+shippingTotal
    +'&utmttx='+taxTotal
    +'&utmcc='+cookies;     // Cookie values. This request parameter sends all the cookies requested from the page.
```

However, from looking at the parameter list at the link below, there is no mention of a currency parameter.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifParameters

So, how do I send the ISO currency code eg USD, GBP, SEK etc?

Comment: you might want to try this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the method above.  Do I still need to send the cookies data?  If not, how does that affect the tracking results?